# Using Thymeleaf when the value is null

Tags: html, null, thymeleaf

I have some values in my database which can be null if they have not already been entered.

But when I use Thymeleaf in my html, it gives an error when parsing null values.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 179):

The shortest way is using '?' operator. If you have User entity with embedded Address entity in order to access fields of Address entity and print them if address is not null, otherwise here will be an empty column:

```
<td th:text="${user?.address?.city}"></td>
```

Note: this feature is from `SpringStandardDialect`, not the Thymeleaf standard dialect.

```
// call it if using thymeleaf without spring mvc
templateEngine.setDialect(new SpringStandardDialect())
```

Comment: The `?.` operator is called the "safe navigation" operator, per the [Spring Expression Language docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation).

Comment: While the above syntax is accepted as valid in spring boot 2.0.5 that comes with thymeleaf 3.0.9, at least for me it does not do what is claimed here. Is that a special feature that you have to enable?

Comment: This feature is not from thymeleaf it is from spring

Comment: using ? on a numeric field that is 0 will also produce false. Thus you'd need to use the full != null conditional on number fields.

Comment: This is the best answer as this is more concise

Comment: I get ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: error in SpringBoot 2.6

Comment: I too get the same exception @sarath got. Using the same version of Spring Boot.

Comment: It got error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user?' available as request attribute

Comment: its a SpringStandardDialect of thymeleaf , non standard non default
to use it detached from spring mvc follow link below:
https://northcoder.com/post/use-springs-thymeleaf-dialect-witho/

Answer (score 87):

Sure there is. You can for example use the [conditional expressions](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions). For example:

```
<span th:text="${someObject.someProperty != null} ? ${someObject.someProperty} : 'null value!'">someValue</span>
```

You can even omit the "else" expression:

```
<span th:text="${someObject.someProperty != null} ? ${someObject.someProperty}">someValue</span>
```

You can also take a look at the [Elvis operator](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator) to display default values like this:-

```
<span th:text="${someObject.someProperty} ?: 'default value'">someValue</span>
```

Comment: `Edit:` Added the `${...}`  for the if condition as you have missed it. +1 for the ternary expression in `th:text`.

Comment: Could you please explain why there are multiple ${...} needed? What if I want to prefix both alternatives with e.g. 'Foo: '. Would I have to specify it twice inside the alternatives?

Comment: Your answer should be admitted as solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

This can also be handled using the [elvis operator](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator) `?:` which will add a default value when the field is null:

```
<span th:text="${object.property} ?: 'default value'"></span>
```

Comment: This is probably the most elegant way showing default values in thymeleaf. deserves way more upvotes!

Answer (score 23):

You can use 'th:if' together with 'th:text'

```
<span th:if="${someObject.someProperty != null}" th:text="${someObject.someProperty}">someValue</span>
```

Comment: No need for `!= null` only  `<span th:if="${someObject.someProperty}"  ...` is enough

Comment: What about th:if for a block why its not working ?

Answer (score 9):

Also worth to look at documentation for #objects build-in helper:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#objects

There is useful: `${#objects.nullSafe(obj, default)}`

Answer (score 8):

You've done twice the checking when you create

```
${someObject.someProperty != null} ? ${someObject.someProperty}
```

You should do it clean and simple as below.

```
<td th:text="${someObject.someProperty} ? ${someObject.someProperty} : 'null value!'"></td>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
   <p data-th-text ="${#strings.defaultString(yourNullable,'defaultValueIfYourValueIsNull')}"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this solution it is working for me

```
<span th:text="${#objects.nullSafe(doctor?.cabinet?.name,'')}"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
<div th:text ="${variable != null} ? (${variable != ''} ? ${variable} : 'empty string message') : 'null message' "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way! it's working for me,
Where NA is my default value.

```
<td th:text="${ins.eValue!=null}? ${ins.eValue}:'NA'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to only display it if it was set. Thymeleaf is being javascripty here:

```html
<span th:unless="${someObject.someProperty}" th:text="${someObject.someProperty}">someValue</span>
```