# Render a list in thymleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have three Entities User, Albums and Photo,
In User l have a collection of Album, in Album l have a collection of photos.
Now in my user.htlm i would like to know foreach user the number of album and the number of photo.
I can get the number of album by using

```
<td th:text="${#lists.size(u.albums)}"></td>
```

How can l get the number of photo?
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code.

```
<td th:text="${#lists.size(u.albums[0].photo)}"></td>
```

Note : You can replace zero with index or counter value during iteration.

Comment: thanks you Alien it's work. However when i try to replace zero with index  have an error "The collection has 1 elements, index '1' is invalid

Comment: Simply add an th:if condition if the u.albums can have zero elements...or add question mark before <td th:text="${u?.albums?.image}"></td> ...refere this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636456/using-thymeleaf-when-the-value-is-null

Comment: now the problem is how can i replace the zero with correct value i already try to do 

    <tr th:each="u, status:${users}">
 after i use status to replace zero by using this code ` <td th:text="${#lists.size(u.albums[status.index]?.photos)}"></td>`

but i have and error because currently there is 1 element in albums so i can't do albums[1]