# Thymeleaf nested object iteration

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to iterate over a list that contains another list.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "session")
public class TrainingSession implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ExerciseWrapper> exercises;

@Column
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY/MM/DD")
private Date sessionDate;
}
```

Adding list to the Model:

```
    @RequestMapping("/sessions")
public String getAllSession(Model model){
    List<TrainingSession> trainingSessionList = trainingSessionService.getAllTrainingSessions();
    model.addAttribute("sessionList", trainingSessionList);
    System.out.println(trainingSessionList);
    return PREFIX+"sessions";
}
```

Iteration:

```
<th:block th:each="trainingSession : ${sessionList}">
<tr><td th:text="${trainingSession.id}"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <th:block th:each="exerciseWrapper : *{trainingSession.exercises}">
        <tr><td th:text="${exerciseWrapper.id}"></td></tr>
        <tr><td th:text="${exerciseWrapper.exercise.name}"></td></tr>
    </th:block>

</tr>
```

This results in error:

> Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

How to access list of exercises?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here:  `*{trainingSession.exercises}`. Here `exerciseWrapper` is null and could not find id from null. Here you used `*` instead of `$`

Try with this:

```
<th:block th:each="trainingSession : ${sessionList}">
<tr><td th:text="${trainingSession.id}"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <th:block th:each="exerciseWrapper : ${trainingSession.exercises}">
        <tr><td th:text="${exerciseWrapper.id}"></td></tr>
        <tr><td th:text="${exerciseWrapper.exercise.name}"></td></tr>
    </th:block>

</tr>
```

If there is possiblilty of exerciseWrapper is null then add `th:if`.

With null check:

```
<th:block th:each="trainingSession : ${sessionList}">
<tr><td th:text="${trainingSession.id}"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <th:block th:each="exerciseWrapper : ${trainingSession.exercises}">
        <tr><td th:if="${exerciseWrapper!=null}" th:text="${exerciseWrapper.id}"></td></tr>
        <tr><td th:if="${exerciseWrapper!=null}" th:text="${exerciseWrapper.exercise.name}"></td></tr>
    </th:block>

</tr>
```

Comment: It seems like exerciseWrapper is null indeed. Which is strange, because when I debug the controller, the exerciseWrapper exists.<br/> . 
Also, the result of<br/>
`<th:block th:each="trainingSession : ${sessionList}">
<tr><td th:text="${trainingSession}"></td></tr>
</tr>` . 
is . 

`TrainingSession{id=16, exercises=[ExerciseWrapper{id=17, exercise=Exercise{id=18, name='Highbar Squat', description='More difficult version of squat'}, weight=115.0, reps=5, rpe=9, notes='Everython okay'}], sessionDate=2018-08-11 12:39:15.093}`

Comment: I said where is your problem.  Change your thymeleaf

Comment: you used * instead of $... *{trainingSession.exercises} will be ${trainingSession.exercises}

Answer (score 0):

You should check first if the information is read completely from database. Try to debug what you put into your model. If it´s already null there, it´s an Hibernate problem.

I think the object you are getting from the first iteration contains a list containing a null element. For dealing with null in Thymeleaf check this question: [Using Thymeleaf when the value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636456/using-thymeleaf-when-the-value-is-null)

Comment: It's not empty. I've debugged it: 
     `[TrainingSession{id=16, exercises=[ExerciseWrapper{id=17, exercise=Exercise{id=18, name='Highbar Squat', description='More difficult version of squat'}, weight=115.0, reps=5, rpe=9, notes='Everython okay'}], sessionDate=2018-08-11 12:39:15.093}]`