# How can I hide <span> when it is empty

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am working on a user login form.
It is on my "home.html" ,

I want to show the username after login(when I get session datas form

"login.html" by "Httpsession")

Otherwise just hide  when it is empty.

```
<span th:text="${user.name}" id="uname"></span>
```

When it is empty, I have an error message like this:

EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Spring, you can use the safe navigation operator - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636456/using-thymeleaf-when-the-value-is-null) for an example. Otherwise, you can use Thymeleaf's `th:if` tag - see [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `th:if` to [conditionally include](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) the `<span>`:

```
<span th:if="${user?.name}" th:text="${user.name}" id="uname"></span>
```

To avoid the NullPointerException, use the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation): `?.`.

Comment: It works! Thx!!And there is no NullPointerException ^ ^